# Mac OS X App file Permissions

Tags: macos, permissions, umask

Our program creates various settings files that it needs to read and write to.  However if the OS X user has a global umask set such that files are created without write permissions, our app cannot write to them.

Requirements:

1. Asking user to change global umask is not an option.
2. Our app should create files that are read/writable by everyone.

I have thought of creating a bash script that sets `umask 000` and then launches are real executable. We would then set the bash script as the executable in our app bundles info.plist.

Does anyone have ideas on what is the best approach to solve this problem?

Comment: Forgot to mention that this program is written in Java

Answer (score 0):

Yon can make a call to `umask()` directly from your code. `umask()` is a Unix's system call which does exactly what you need. RTFM `umask` in section 2.

Comment: I answered with the same solution yesterday.  Next @ntmp will tell you that his app is implemented in Java...